# Using Djongo package with django applications

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

I am making a `Django` application which needs `MongoDB` as the backend database. I have used `djongo` (https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/)
to get this `MongoDB` connected to `Django`.

But then I add the following line in `models.py`:

```
from djongo import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.EmbeddedModelField(
        model_container=Blog,
    ) 

    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And when I go to admin panel to add an entry I get the following error:

```
SQLDecodeError at /admin/app/entry/
FAILED SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "app_entry"
Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('ok', 0.0), ('errmsg', "Unrecognized pipeline 
stage name: '$count'"), ('code', 16436)])
```

Version: 1.2.24

Can anyone help me out here, please?

Thank You

Comment: What is the mongo version you are using

Comment: The MongoDB version I am using is 3.2.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From djongo package [requirements](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo#requirements)

> 2. MongoDB 3.4 or higher.

Also same is mentioned at start of link you have provided

Comment: Upgrade guide Ubuntu: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-using-deb-packages


Upgrade guide Debian: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ 


Upgrade guide Mac: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/